# How do you change your password on Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, login, stack-exchange-openid

I'm trying to find how I change my Stack Exchange access password. I can edit my account, change the icon, but where oh where is the password update area?

Answer (score 4):

Click "my logins" link near to "network profile". Then I can see "Stack Exchange (change password)"

Comment: That's it, all set. I'm too tired and too cranky for all this, I looked right past it.